# Passar value do input OnkeyPress do button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input:

```
<input id="in_cpf_cnpj" name="cpf_cnpj" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o CNPJ" required autofocus></>
```

Preciso enviar o valor do mesmo, como parametro, para uma função através do OnClick de um button, estou tentando da seguinte maneira, mas não funciona.

```
<button class="btn btn-block bg-red waves-effect" onclick="validaCampo('cnpj', in_cpf_cnpj.value" type="button">Confirmar</button>
```

o código da função validaCampo:

```
function validaCampo(tipo, valor) {
    //Tipos: CNPJ,
    if (tipo != '') {
        //valida cnpj
        if (tipo == 'cnpj') {
            valor = valor.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
            debugger;
            if (valor == '') return false;

            if (valor.length != 14)
                return false;

            // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
            if (valor == "00000000000000" ||
                valor == "11111111111111" ||
                valor == "22222222222222" ||
                valor == "33333333333333" ||
                valor == "44444444444444" ||
                valor == "55555555555555" ||
                valor == "66666666666666" ||
                valor == "77777777777777" ||
                valor == "88888888888888" ||
                valor == "99999999999999")
                return false;

            // Valida DVs
            tamanho = valor.length - 2
            numeros = valor.substring(0, tamanho);
            digitos = valor.substring(tamanho);
            soma = 0;
            pos = tamanho - 7;
            for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
                soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
                if (pos < 2)
                    pos = 9;
            }
            resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
            if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
                return false;

            tamanho = tamanho + 1;
            numeros = valor.substring(0, tamanho);
            soma = 0;
            pos = tamanho - 7;
            for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
                soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
                if (pos < 2)
                    pos = 9;
            }
            resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
            if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Falta fechar parentesis aqui: `validaCampo('cnpj', in_cpf_cnpj.value`. Podes colocar no teu código `validaCampo`? Assim podemos ajudar mais a perceber o que pode estar a falhar.

Comment: @Sergio, editei o conteúdo e acrescentei a função, sei que poderia informar o nome do campo dentro dela, mas para seguir um padrão, gostaria de passar via parâmetro

Comment: @Sergio, a primeira opção deu erro, mas a segunda funcionou blz. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta um parêntesis no teu código, e sugiro outra maneira de enviar o valor do input:

Alternativa 1 é manter a função como está e fazer:

```
onclick="validaCampo('cnpj', document.getElementByID('in_cpf_cnpj').value)"
```

Outra alternativa melhor seria ter assim no HTML:

```
onclick="validaCampo('cnpj', 'in_cpf_cnpj')"
```

e na função assim:

```
function validaCampo(tipo, name) {

    var input = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"']);
    var valor = input.value;
    // o resto igual
```